# How to get my file JSON using WWW class then deserialize it to array?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I want to get my JSON file in server then deserialize it to the gameobject...
So, I'm sure I've to use `WWW` class...

This is my script

```
IEnumerator LoadPertanyaanData() {

    WWW wwwDataFilePath = new WWW (dataFilePath);
    yield return wwwDataFilePath;

    string dataAsJSON = wwwDataFilePath.text;
    DataController loadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<DataController> (dataAsJSON);
    allKategori = loadedData.allKategori;

}
```

And I have some error :

ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize JSON to new instances of type 'DataController.'
UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson[DataController] (System.String json) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/modules/JSONSerialize/JsonUtilityBindings.gen.cs:24)
DataController+c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/DataController.cs:35)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)

Comment: What's the value of `dataFilePath`?

Comment: @zwcloud I'm still using local database `http://localhost/game/data.json`...

Comment: Please provide FULL log of the error. Edit your question.

Comment: edited @zwcloud

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be with this line:

```
string dataAsJSON = File.ReadAllText(wwwDataFilePath.text);
```

The `File.ReadAllText` method takes a **local** filename or path. It will throw an `ArgumentException` if its input contains certain characters that are invalid in local file path names.

You seem to be getting this exception because, as per your comment, the input string is `http://localhost/game/data.json`, which contains the invalid character `:`.

The `text` property on the `WWW` object is all you need to get a `string` from the remote URL:

```
string dataAsJSON = wwwDataFilePath.text;
```

Comment: Ow yeah of course... Thanks... :)
But then I've another error, 'ArgumentException : Cannot deserialize JSON to new instances of type DataController'...

Comment: @Shiro About how to serialize and deserialize json, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/serialize-and-deserialize-json-and-json-array-in-unity/36244111#36244111).

Comment: @Shiro Is 'DataController' a `MonoBehaviour`? JsonUtility can only be used for classes that aren't `MonoBehaviour`s, and are marked with the `[System.Serializable]` attribute.